# ExpressJS: run a function every 24 hours

Tags: javascript, express

What's the easiest way to run an automated function every 24 hours in ExpressJS?

I have searched everywhere for a solution aside from running an infinite loop. Is this in principle the only way to do it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you need to use [node-cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron) npm

```
var cron = require('node-cron');


cron.schedule('0 0 * * *', () => {
  console.log('running a task every day');
});
```

get other cron formula :https://crontab.guru/examples.html

Answer (score 6):

In Javascript, you use `setTimeout()` and `setInterval()` to schedule something to run a specific amount of time into the future (details [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval)).  `setTimeout()` will run it once at the specific time interval from now.  `setInterval()` will run it over and over again at that particular time interval.

If this is a server that's running constantly, you can just use `setInterval()`.

```
setInterval(myFunction, 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
```

This will call your function `myFunction` every 24 hours.

There are also various chron packages such as [node-schedule](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule) you can find on NPM that have more sophisticated scheduling tools (run it every other day and twice on Mondays) and can offer persistence so scheduling is remembered across a server restart.

For example, I have a home automation server running on a raspberry Pi that uses a `setInterval()` to run some log management code once a day.

Comment: I feel like this should be the top answer, as setInterval does the job without an external dependency. Thanks for the explanation!